# How to integrate $\int_{0}^{\infty} t^{-\frac{3}{2}} e^{-at - \frac{b}{t}}dt$ without gamma function?

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

How to solve this type of integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty} t^{-\frac{3}{2}} e^{-at - \frac{b}{t}}dt
\end{equation}
where $a$ and $b$ are positive.

Please help me out with the integration without using the gamma function.

Comment: I conjecture that Gamma function, in the simplest case, being defined to be $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{n-1} e^{-x} dx$; was derived for computing the integrals of the appearance. So, you should express this integral in terms of the Gamma one; or you might attempt at solving the integral by applying integral transformations (Laplace transform and Fourier + Fubini theorem). Which besides, you may introduce an function and by Feynman's algorithm solve the integral. Give it a try.

Comment: See 10.32.10 on [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32).

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $t=\sqrt{\frac ba    }\frac1{x^2 }$

\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\infty} t^{-\frac{3}{2}} e^{-at - \frac{b}{t}}dt
&=\sqrt[4]{\frac ab  } e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\sqrt{ab }\>(x-\frac1{x})^2}dx\\ 
&= \sqrt[4]{\frac ab } e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\sqrt{ab }\>x^2}dx\\
&=\sqrt[4]{\frac ab  } e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt\pi}{\sqrt[4]{ab}}= \sqrt{\frac\pi b} e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}
\end{align}
where $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-cx^2}dx=\sqrt{\frac \pi c}$ and $
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f\left(x-\frac 1x \right) dx
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx
$
are used.

Comment: That's a very interesting fact about $f\left(x-\frac1x\right)$. Can you point to a derivation?

Comment: @DavidK - see proof below
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f\left(x-\frac 1x \right) dx
&= \int_{-\infty}^{0} 
\overset{x=- e^{-t}} {f\left(x-\frac 1x \right) dx }+ \int_{0}^{\infty} \overset{x= e^t}{f\left(x-\frac 1x \right) dx}\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(e^t-e^{-t})(e^t +e^{-t}) dt
 =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx
\end{align}

Comment: That's beautiful.

Comment: @DavidK [There's a famous generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem).